# Re-adding a control to the controls collection issue

Tags: c#, winforms

Please help me with the following issue:

Scenario:

1. If `ComboBox` is not `null`: `Controls.Remove(ComboBox)`, `ComboBox.Dispose()`
2. Create a new `ComboBox` (with new `DataSource`,`DisplayMember`,etc)
3. Add the new `ComboBox` to `Controls`: `Controls.Add(ComboBox)`
4. go to 1.

The issue:
When I re-adding my `ComboBox` (with new properties in place) to the `Controls` collection, properties (exactly `ComboBox.Items` collection) of the previous `ComboBox` are assigned (override) to the new one just added.

Can you provide me any suggestion what is (or could) happening here, please?

Thanks

C# Code:

```
private void DropDownCell(CellIndex cell, object dropDownData, string displayMember) {

        // Remove previous drop-down, if any
        if( DropDownBox != null ) {
            var garbageDropDownBox = DropDownBox;
            DropDownBox = null;
            Controls.Remove(garbageDropDownBox);
            garbageDropDownBox.Dispose();
        }

        // Create up the dropdown:
        var dropDownBox = new ComboBox() {
            DataSource = dropDownData,
            DisplayMember = displayMember,              
            DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown,
            MaxDropDownItems = 25,
            AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend,
            Margin = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 0),
            Font = new Font(Family, CellFont.Size, CellFont.Style, CellFont.Unit),
            Location = Point.Round(GetViewPoint(GetLogicalCellRect(cell).Location))
        };
        // Set the background color
        bool editable = true, editableKnown = true;
        var brush = SheetStyle.GetBackBrush(source, source.GetColumn(cell.Column), cell.Row, ref editableKnown, ref editable) as SolidBrush;
        if( brush != null )
            dropDownBox.BackColor = brush.Color;

        // Tie up events to the drop down
        dropDownBox.SelectionChangeCommitted += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if( sender == DropDownBox )
                try {
                    source.GetColumn(cell.Column).SetDropDownItem(cell.Row, dropDownBox.SelectedItem);
                } catch( Exception ex ) {
                    Logger.Debug(ex);
                }
        });
        dropDownBox.DropDownClosed += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if( sender == DropDownBox )
                try {
                    dropDownBox.Visible = false;
                    Focus();
                    //FocusIndex = cell;
                } catch {
                }
        });
        // Add the control and calculate the optimal width based on contents
        Controls.Add(dropDownBox);
        object currentValue = source.GetColumn(cell.Column).GetRawValue(cell.Row);
        using( Graphics g = dropDownBox.CreateGraphics() ) {
            float width = dropDownBox.Width - SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;
            foreach( DataRowView item in dropDownBox.Items ) {
                if( object.Equals(item[displayMember], currentValue) )
                    dropDownBox.SelectedItem = item;
                width = Math.Max(width, g.MeasureString(dropDownBox.GetItemText(item), dropDownBox.Font).Width);
            }
            dropDownBox.Width = (int)width + SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;
        }
        // Scroll to drop down and open it
        ScrollToCell(cell);
        dropDownBox.DroppedDown = true;
        dropDownBox.Focus();
        DropDownBox = dropDownBox;
    }
```

Comment: Out of interest, why can;t you just update the properties? As it's a UI control, it shouldn't need to be destroyed and recreated...

Comment: @Tomas: I've added the method that do the thing. (Sorry, I do not know how to format a code block in SO)

Comment: @Deanna: I get an exception at "if(bject.Equals(item[displayMember],..." the "item" does not have the "displayMember" column name, and it is because Items are from the previouse dropDownBox

Comment: @Deanna: I need to create a ComboBox, only when the user is clicking on the datasheet cell that has property of the dropdownbox. After the user made his selection, I am disposing the ComboBox control, and user will see an ordinary cell with selected value

Answer (score 0):

In step 2, be sure to not just change the properties of the `ComboBox` but to really create a new instance:

```
Controls.Remove(ComboBox);
ComboBox.Dispose();
ComboBox = new ComboBox(); // <<- !! important
ComboBox.DataSource = ...;
Controls.Add(ComboBox);
```